# How to create a site map using javascript

Tags: javascript, web-crawler, web-scraping

I am looking for documentation on how to create a javascript which will follow all the links on a page, or site, and create a map or list of them. Or, if there is a better way to do this, that would be great too. I am just trying to get a comprehensive list of all the pages on a site with 3000+ pages. I also don't know what tags to put on this question, so tips in that area would be chill.

Comment: It looks to me like you are trying to implement a crawler of some-kind

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is referred to as:

1. web crawling
2. screen scraping

Use google and you'll be able to find a solution in the technology you prefer.

I personally like the python package [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/)

**UPDATE:** for instance, just searching for "javascript screen scraping tutorial" gives you: [pjScrape](http://nrabinowitz.github.com/pjscrape/) a web scraping framework written in javascript